# PHP WebSocket Daemon

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I have set up a WebSocket server in php using Ratchet running as a daemon - exposed by Varnish cache.

However there is a big problem i see in it - the lack of threads in php. Is there anything i can do to pass on data for processing without hanging the whole server? Is it possible in PHP or should i just move to a different technology - node.js for example - but seeing as the main project is in PHP it would be complicated to make that work together. If any option to do this in PHP is available id prefer it.

Comment: I have no experience with it, but have heard of [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads).

Comment: @ceejayoz - wow ! will check out right away, thanks.

Comment: pthreads is nice, check out reddit thread http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1jo517/multithreading_in_php_with_pthreads/

Comment: @ceejayoz plz post as answer, threads in PHP is what i was looking for.

Comment: @n00b Cool, will do. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads is a library I've heard mentioned a lot (but haven't personally used). Enjoy!